# Which factors may affect a choice of an oviposition place in nocturnal moths?

Tags: entomology, ecology, ethology

Winter Moth (*Operophtera brumata*) is a small brachypterous (females have stunned wings - unable to fly) moth which places eggs on thick branches.

I would like to know which abiotic and biotic factors may play a role in selection of place for oviposition. Taking into account that **level of humidity is probably the same on whole tree** (and probably whole forest) and the branches are so thick that they are not distinguishionable from surrounding environment (and **there is no accumulated heat to identify their orientation** (south, north etc.)

**What other factors may play a role?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The winter moth's preferred host plants are mainly deciduous trees, oak being the main food plant and also many fruit trees, birch and hazel. Females generally deposit eggs in bark crevices, under bark scales, bark snags and under lichen along tree trunks of host species. Eggs are initially small and green but gradually change colour to orange and then red before hatching ([reference 1](http://extension.umass.edu/fruitadvisor/news/winter-moth-operophtera-brumata) and [reference 2](http://www.goert.ca/documents/Operophtera-brumata.pdf)).

Though the oak is preferred,

> There does not seem to be much discrimination in selection of host
>   plant or oviposition site by the female ([Wint 1983](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/4564?uid=3737496&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104231472941)), as the choice of
>   larval food plant depends on the female's pupation site and the
>   direction she takes on emerging, as she just climbs up the nearest
>   tree. So it might be fair to say that the larvae contribute more to
>   host plant choice than the adults, as the larvae can balloon if the
>   host plant is unsuitable. However there is the possibility that year
>   after year each generation of females will climb up the same tree as
>   their mother, and oaks (one of the most common host plants) can be
>   hundreds of years old, so there could have been hundreds of
>   generations of winter moth on the same tree ([reference](http://www.bumblebee.org/HomeworkAnswers/Essay3.htm)).

So that in effect means, that the thickness of branches or being indistinguishable should not be a factor. Regarding abiotic and biotic condition, the main abiotic conditions are precipitation, temperature and photoperiod.

An increase in temperature leads to more activity and a faster metabolism ([reference](http://www.ibles.pl/documents/13012/495762/jaworski13-4-7-e.pdf)) Since leaf buds open faster, there is a chance for eggs to be laid faster according because the larva needs to burrow into the buds before the leaf opens (bud-burst) Hatching is temperature dependant but I do not think that it effects the number of eggs much. Biotic factors like the presence of parasitic predators reduce population but does not seem to reduce the number of eggs.. ([reference](http://irs.ub.rug.nl/dbi/5062c89611062))